# Method Ref in arrays

Tags: java-8

I have a `stream` like so. Is it possible to change from `.map(i->arr[i])` to something like .map(arr) since both are i?

```
public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(IntStream.range(0, position).map(i->arr[i]).toArray());
    }
```

Comment: You cannot, it's not a function.

Comment: So from what I read and understood, its not possible to use method references when either there are the multiple params or when we stream on arrays? Is that correct?

Comment: I cannot agree with you, since your statement is misleading. You can obtain a reference to a function surely.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, position).collect(Collectors.toArray())`

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to express `i -> arr[i]` with a method reference.  However, `Arrays` class contains methods that can streamline this code.

You can use [3-argument `Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-int-int-) to avoid streaming over indexes:   `Arrays.stream(arr, 0, position)` is equivalent to `IntStream.range(0, position).map(i -> arr[i])`

Since all you are doing with the stream is making a new array out of it, you can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, position)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) to avoid making a stream altogether.

Comment: Even shorter, `Arrays.copyOf(arr, position)`. Or considering that the final goal is a string representation, `Arrays.stream(arr, 0, position).mapToObj(String::valueOf) .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"))`